# How to understand nested monitors leading to deadlocks?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, monitor

From Programming Language Pragmatics, by Scott

> While **maintaining exclusion on outer monitor(s) when waiting in an
>   inner one** may lead to deadlock with a signaling thread, **releasing
>   those outer monitors** may lead to similar (if a bit more subtle)
>   deadlocks. When a waiting thread awakens it must reacquire exclusion
>   on both inner and outer monitors. The innermost monitor is of course
>   available, because the matching signal happened there, but there is in
>   general no way to ensure that unrelated threads will not be busy in
>   the outer monitor(s). Moreover one of those threads may need access to
>   the inner monitor in order to complete its work and release the outer
>   monitor(s). If we insist that the awakened thread be the ﬁrst to run
>   in the inner monitor after the signal, then deadlock will result. One
>   way to avoid this problem is to arrange for mutual exclusion across
>   all the monitors of a program. This solution severely limits
>   concurrency in multiprocessor implementations, but may be acceptable
>   on a uniprocessor.

How do the two cases highlighted by me in bold lead to deadlocks?

- maintaining exclusion on outer monitor(s) when waiting in an inner one
- releasing those outer monitors

I have trouble to understand the text, especially for the second case.
Would appreciate any help to explain them in a clearer way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**maintaining exclusion on outer monitor(s) when waiting in an inner one** When a process is waiting on an inner monitor it can keep the exclusion on all outer monitors it is maintaining. This may lead to a deadlock when another process wants access to one of the outer monitors, but has access to the inner one on it's own, creating a deadlock.

**releasing those outer monitors**: Imagine a thread waiting for an inner monitor and releasing his outers to ensure that some others may gain access to them while the process is waiting. Now when the thread awakens (=the inner monitor is free to access it again),it needs to get the outer monitor which it released while waiting. And here comes the problem with this one: " but there is in general no way to ensure that unrelated threads will not be busy in the outer monitor(s)"

Comment: Thanks. That makes more sense. What does the quote mean by "One way to avoid this problem is to arrange for mutual exclusion across all the monitors of a program"?

Comment: Mutual Exclusion is one way to ensure concurrency control. What this phrase means is to define the whole section of the code where monitors exist (where concurrent file access may happen) as the critical section. This means only one thread can execute his critical section at a time and there is no possibility of deadlocks since no two threads may access monitors at the same time. As stated in the last sentence, this is highly unefficient as you might have guesses though :)

Answer (score 1):

See the case,the code like:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {     //thread 1
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (outer){
                synchronized (inner){
                    try {
                        outer.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {   //thread2
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (outer){
                System.out.println("get outer");
                synchronized (inner){
                    System.out.println("get inner");
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

The thread1 will release the outer monitor,but still hold the inner monitor,when the thread2 run,it will acquire the outer monitor successfully,but can't acquire the inner monitor.This will occurs deadlock.

And see the other case:
change the `outer.wait();` to `inner.wait();`,this still occur deadlock.
Because the thread1 will hold the outer monitor,and the `thread2` will not acquire that.

Comment: Thanks. Does `synchronized` here implement a monitor?

Comment: @Tim Yes,the `synchronized` is a keyword of the java ,which is a implementation of monitor.The `JLS 17.1` explain: `The most basic of these methods is synchronization, which is implemented using monitors. Each object in Java is associated with a monitor, which a thread can lock or unlock. Only one thread at
a time may hold a lock on a monitor. Any other threads attempting to lock that monitor are blocked until they can obtain a lock on that monitor. A thread t may lock a particular monitor multiple times; each unlock reverses the effect of one lock operation.`

Comment: Thanks, dabaicai!